# Jquery Script validation using GeekTantra plugin

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm looking for a bit of help with a validation rule with the geektantra plugin.

I have this working fine but have one requirement I can't seem to figure out.

On my form I have multiple input text fields, a dropdown and a check box.

The checkbox determines if the dropdown is active or not. This works fine.

Currently I have this as a rule for the dropdown.  if the value isn't 0 then OK, else 'Required Field'

```
    jQuery("#area").validate({
        expression: "if (VAL != '0') return true; else return false;",
        message: "Required Field"
    });
```

The issue is this is active all the time even when the dropdown is disabled.
I'm looking to have it active only when the dropdown is enabled.

I've tried :

```
    jQuery("#area").validate({
        expression: "if (isChecked('drop') && VAL != '0') return true; else return false;",
        message: "Required Field"
    });

    jQuery("#area").validate({
        expression: "if ($('#drop').is(':checked') && VAL != '0') return true; else return false;",
        message: "Required Field"
    });
```

And lots of other variations but none seem to work..

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this by editing **jquery.validate.js** and added an `if else` within `function validate_field(id){` so it doesn't validate disabled fields.